# Cannot find /Users/user/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh

Tags: macos, bash, tomcat, terminal

This file is needed to run this program. I am new to Mac OS X and its terminal.

I am installing Apache Tomcat, using steps provided through this URL [`http://www.editrocket.com/articles/tomcat_mac.html`](http://www.editrocket.com/articles/tomcat_mac.html), but when I run

```
sh startup.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find /Users/user/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh
 This file is needed to run this program.
```

Whereas `setclasspath.sh` already exists at this location.

Comment: What happens if you use `${HOME}` in place of `/Users/user`?

Comment: Your permissions are probably not set right. Paste the output of the following command: ls -al

Answer (score 4):

Check your **CATALINA_HOME** by doing `echo $CATALINA_HOME`

This should point to your where tomcat is installed.

Add this line in your `~/.bash_profile` and source it.

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/path/to/tomcat-x.x
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I've come across this issue, as I have multiple instances of Tomcat on my dev machine, and tend to have them in subdirectories of my user account, to keep them separate from what comes stock with OS X.

I've found it's better to have these sorts of settings self-contained, that is, in a `setenv.sh` file, for each instance.

SO, for example, if John Doe is running Tomcat v7.0.49, from within some directory he's created:

> /Users/johndoe/Server/app/tomcat-7.0.49/bin/setenv.sh

And in that file:

> export CATALINA_BASE="/Users/johndoe/Server/app/tomcat-7.0.49"
>   export CATALINA_HOME="/Users/johndoe/Server/app/tomcat-7.0.49"

This will work, pretty much from anywhere. You're now telling this particular Tomcat instance where to look for itself. Keep in mind, if you have multiple instances of the same Tomcat version in the same directory, you'll need to give each a unique parent folder name.

Also worthy of mention, CATALINA_BASE is optional, and will default to CATALINA_HOME, if you leave it out. Listing both is simply my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question.
I fixed this by specifying the full path of of `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable;

I changed;

```
CATALINA_HOME="~/Servers/tomcat"
```

To;

```
CATALINA_HOME="/Users/{my_username}/Servers/tomcat"
```

It's not supposed to make a difference but for some reason it does.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled your error and found the following result from [malisphoto](http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/tomcatonosx.html):

> If you received the error "Cannot find /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/setclasspath.sh," you are probably trying to install Tomcat in your home directory Library (`~/Library`). Either install Tomcat in the root Library (`/Library`) or point `CATALINA_HOME` to your home directory Tomcat installation directory, probably something like `CATALINA_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Tomcat/Home`. A basic installation doesn't require setting `CATALINA_HOME` or `JAVA_HOME` for that matter.

If this is not your issue, I would suggest trying to open the file directly from the terminal using that same string of text, to make sure that the file is definitely there.

Comment: @user1905811 No i have not installed Tomcat in my library directory, Its is being installed under username. I tried running  this command as you mentioned CATALINA_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Tomcat/Home     but nothing happened . Still i am not able to launch sh startup.sh

Answer (score 0):

You need to set two lines at two places:
The path details are:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.90
```

Put these paths at the end of the lines.
Files that you want to edit:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

and

```
./shutdown.sh
./startup.sh
```